# Limitations Of ETL with respect to Various Algorithm Processing

Tags: java, mapreduce, apache-pig, etl, talend

I was wondering the problems that cannot be solved by ETL. Like we all know , we can extract data, do some transformations and processing, and store that  transformed data into a data store, The processing can be pretty complex in ETL as well.

So what is the scope of writing Java Codes, if everything can be done using ETL apart from building a UI application using J2EE.

Which kind of algorithms run well in ETL and which type of algorithms should be run outside ETL.

I am more of like talking about ETL tools and not ETL as a concept in this respect, like Talend is a tool where code is auto-generated(specific to how the ETL Vendor has implemented) versus writing own code to make it happen, for say, to change implementations to improve memory efficiency against time efficiency or improve time efficiency against memory efficiency, and more so ever, make things generic in nature..!!

So In this respect, while making products and writing algorithms, should we use Standared ETL Tools or custom code is advisable for long term goals.

Can somebody elaborate on this topic with use cases and examples where ETL fails or has a limitations.

Thanks in Advance :)!!

Comment: ETL is a very broad concept.  Anything that moves data from one system to another might be considered ETL.  What ETL-related task are you needing to do?

Comment: @mellamokb, Hi.!! the task I am trying to is : Group Data Based on Phone Numbers from a data source consisting of various other call details, then iterate that group per phone number and compute some KPI like call duration, how many times the phone number has made calls, avg. time between making next calls, etc. I have written them in Map Reduce. But I was reading that it can be done using tools like Talend or any ETL tool as well. I wanted to know which kind of Algorithms is good for ETL and which kind of Algorithms are not good in ETL. Thanks for replying.

Answer (score 1):

As mellamokb mentioned ETL is a concept. Anytime you are extracting data from a data source, transforming it and loading it to another data store you are doing ETL. Sometimes the "T" in its strict sense is optional because you may simply be moving data as is.

As for performing ETL, you could do it using tools such as Informatica and DataStage or code it yourself using Java, PLSQL or some other language. The tools often offer a visual interface and allow abstraction of several details but functionally you could perform the same yourself. So the choice is not between ETL and Java it is between using a tool and doing it yourself.

---

Your questions

**Q1)** *So what is the scope of writing Java Codes, if everything can be done using ETL apart from building a UI application using J2EE.*

Java is a general purpose programming language. You could solve almost any problem that can be solved with programming using it including ETL. There are way too many problem types in the problem domain: networking, database software, OS software, word processing ...

**Q2)** *Which kind of algorithms run well in ETL and which type of algorithms should be run outside ETL.*

The question should not be about algorithms it should be about which problems fall under ETL scope. If you understand the meaning of ETL it should be rather obvious.

**Q3)** *Can somebody elaborate on this topic with use cases and examples where ETL fails or has limitations.*

Again, ETL is a concept. Use case of when ETL fails doesn't make much sense. If you mean to ask when ETL tools fail that would be a reasonable question. The answer depends on what you are trying to achieve and what features your tool supports. Most tools these days support myriads of data sources and targets and allow you to extend the supplied transformations by writing your own code using varied languages including Java.

Comment: Hi @Owl, I was more of like talking about ETL tools like Talend where code is autogenerated vs writing own code to make it , say more memory efficient and more generic in nature..!!

Comment: Hi @Owl, I was more of like talking about ETL tools and not ETL as a concept in this respect, like Talend is a tool where code is auto-generated(specific to how the ETL Vendor has implemented) versus writing own code to make it happen, for say, to change implementations to improve memory efficiency against time efficiency or improve time efficiency against memory efficiency, and  more so ever, make things generic in nature..!! So In this respect, while making products and writing algorithms, should we use Standared ETL Tools or custom code is advisable for long term goals.